# Node JS print thermal printer via USB Port especially connect with typeC HUB

Tags: node.js, printing, thermal-printer

I am working on nodejs and thermal printer. Currently it's work with ip via ethernet cable same network. I'm using [node thermal printer npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-thermal-printer)

but now I connected the printer with typeC Hub. How can i handle that? How can i print via usb port as a crossplatform.

I found any other usb detect library and it's gave me this result:

```
 {
    locationId: 17891328,
    vendorId: 1155,
    productId: 22304,
    deviceName: 'Printer',
    manufacturer: 'Printer',
    serialNumber: '11101800002',
    deviceAddress: 4
  }
```